# How to customize the background color of the item picker using native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

Hello My Friend please help Me, I have difficulty in customizing picker using native base,

How to customize the background color of the item picker using a native base so that it can be displayed on an Android device?

Thank you for someone who can answer this question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add backgroundColor as below,

```
<Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    iosHeader="Select your SIM"
    style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    selectedValue={this.state.selected}
    onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
>
    <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
    <Picker.Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
    <Picker.Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
    <Picker.Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
    <Picker.Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
</Picker>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you customize the background color in Picker.Item?

Comment: @BenzIskan do you want to give different color for each picker items

Comment: Yes, I want to give a different color to each picker items , Please tell me how to do it :)

Comment: check this - https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-text-and-item-text-styles-headref but this currently work with iOS only & there are no props to change background color of the individual item.